# JWT Issuer Invalid Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt

My JWT isn't being validated because the issuer claim is failing and I don't know why
Creating the token looks like this:

```cs
            var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["JWT:Secret"]);
            var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(
                new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), 
                SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
               issuer: _config["JWT:Issuer"],
               claims: claims,
               notBefore: DateTime.Now,
               expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20),
               signingCredentials: signingCredentials
               );
```

and in my Startup.cs file I validate the token as such:

```cs
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
                {
                    options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.ClaimsIssuer = Configuration["JWT:Issuer"];
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JWT:Secret"])),
                        // works when set to false
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidateAudience = false,
                        ValidateLifetime = true
                    };
                });
```

So then why am I getting this error:

> Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The issuer 'LoggerApp' is invalid"

note: _config and Configuration are the same dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `ValidIssuer` property of `TokenValidationParameters` to make sure issuer validation works :

```
ValidateIssuer = true,
ValidIssuer = Configuration["JWT:Issuer"],
```

Comment: Yes I figured that out soon after posting but forgot to update my question, thanks though.

Comment: @nan_yu. it was working in developmentwithoutany valid issuer set  but not in test.....any explanation? i looked at the source...itchecks if cfg.validissuers is null, assigns to configuration.issuer n then concatenates if its not null.assume cfg mgr is from the discovery end point. should i add'/v2.0' at the end for v 2.0 tokens.